# Why does the prefix "super-" change the word class of the noun "strength", while the adjective "superstrong" exists?

Tags: word-usage, prefixes, word-class

According to the Merriam-Webster Dictionary, ***super-*** is a prefix meaning either "bigger, better, or more important than others of the same kind" or "superior in position or rank." The following is a pair of typical examples of how the prefix affects the meaning and word class of a word:

> **superpower**
>
> *noun*
>
> 1: excessive or superior power
>
> 2: an extremely powerful nation

and

> **superpowerful**
>
> *adjective*
>
> extremely powerful.

As we see, under the addition of the prefix, the word class is preserved, and the meaning changes accordingly.

However, I found the following example, which seems inconsistent with the expected pattern:

> **superstrength**
>
> adjective
>
> having extremely great strength.

We see that adding the prefix changes the word class of "strength" from noun to adjective. Nevertheless, it is worth noting that we have the following word with the same meaning but complying with the expected pattern:

> **superstrong**
>
> Adjective
>
> extremely strong.

So, the following questions arise:

- Is this unusual behavior of the formation of "superstrength" not inconsistent with prescribed grammar rules?
- If not, why do we need the word "superstrength" while the word "superstrong" has the same meaning and usage?

---

#### Addendum

- As there are opinions suggesting that usage of the word "superstrength" seems somewhat incorrect or informal, let me add the following sentence from an article of Scientific American Magazine, which inspired me to post this question here:

> The moon has an abundance of raw
> materials that could be processed to
> yield aluminum, ceramics and ***superstrength*** glasses for the construction
> of telescopes.[emphasis added]

- It seems that a crucial point of this post might not be apparent enough to be dealt with, so let me highlight it here. I mentioned the typical example involving the word "power", which is similar to "strength" in meaning. I indicated that by adding the prefix "super-" to "power" we get a *noun* from a *noun*, and to "powerful" we get an *adjective* from an *adjective*, noting that the obtained words get meanings we already expect. So, I expected that the same situation should happen to the word "strength." I wonder why my expectation turned to be wrong. In other words, what is the difference between the words "power" and "strength" so that they display different behaviors when adding the prefix "super-"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - But _high-strength_ is used attributively, so why not _superstrength_?

Comment: I think using "super" as a general-purpose intensifier is a bit "downmarket" *(Download our super easy app from our super good website)*. So regardless of whether they're fused into single-word terms, there's not much meaning to pronouncements about "correct usage" with ***superstrong / superstrength***. Correct usage would be things like ***very strong*** and (possibly hyphenated) ***high strength***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for sharing your opinion. I added the sentence in which I saw that word.

Comment: You don't need to provide a link to prove that attributive "superstrength" does occur occasionally. That's not in dispute. But as [*this usage chart*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=superstrength+glasses%2Csuper+strength+glasses%2Csuper-strength+glasses%2Chigh+strength+glasses&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), none of ***superstrength glasses, super strength glasses*** or ***super-strength glasses*** occur often enough in print to show on the chart, because it's too "casual". To be "correct", use (optionally hyphenated)  ***high strength glasses***.

Comment: What does "while having superstrong" mean??

Answer (score 4):

Superstrength is a fairly casual noun for talking about what Superman and Mr Incredible have.

Like many nouns, it can be used attributively, in this case usually in a hyperbolic way.  "Buy this superstrength kitchen paper".

Many dictionaries (including M-W) call nouns used attributively "adjectives". "Superstrength" probably isn't an adjective, as it can't form a comparative (it doesn't have the morphology of an adjective) and it can't be modified by adverbs (it doesn't have the syntax of an adjective). You can't say "more superstrength than" or "very superstrength".

Unless you *are* talking about Mr Incredible, avoid words like "superstrength". They sound rather silly in most contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I know, not all adjectives can be modified/intensified; for example, *absolute adjective* such as "dead" cannot be modified or intensified. Regarding your final point, I added the sentence in which I saw that word to the OP.

Comment: Even for the "supers," I would render "superstrength" as "super strength", or possibly "super-strength."

Comment: The prohibition on "very dead" is because that is an oxymoron, not because dead isn't an adjective.  "very dead" is like "green ideas".

Comment: I think that the word "dead", as one example of many, cannot be intensified by "very" because "dead" is an absolute adjective. Anyway, do you agree with me that impossibility of intensifying a word by, say, "very" does not necessarily implies that the word is not an adjective, because there are absolute adjectives that cannot be intensified?

Comment: By the way, you noted that many dictionaries call nouns used attributively adjectives. I cannot grasp your point. Many nouns can be used attributively while they are marked *noun* in dictionaries. Please also see my second point in the addendum section.

Comment: Okay, to put this more bluntly.  The marking of "superstrength" as an adjective in that dictionary is a mistake.  The dictionary is wrong.  It is not an adjective. It can't be modified by adverbs.  It is a noun.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the definition you provided, I think superstrength is a noun, not an adjective. Superstrong is the adjective.

> This glue has superstrength.

> This glue is superstrong.